# Force Docker Swarm container distribution

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I currently have a 10 container Jenkins setup in my docker swarm environment which includes 3 masters and 4 slave nodes.  I rebooted both masters and slaves a few minutes ago and noticed all the containers now showing up on one node when i do a `docker ps`. Not evenly distributed across masters and slaves.

Is there a way for me to force docker to evenly distribute the containers across my swarm masters and slaves?

EDIT

```
root@docker1  ~   master  docker version
Client:
Version:      1.12.3
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   6b644ec
Built:
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.12.3
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   6b644ec
Built:
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64`
```

Comment: What version of Swarm are you using, is this 1.12.0 with Swarm mode enabled? There was a known bug restarting the Manager set that would end up with all the containers on one node. You are probably hitting that case. Maybe draining that one node would help spreading back the containers to the other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

As docker 1.12.3 there is no way to evenly rebalance/redistribute containers on swarm nodes after a failure.

But you can try these workarounds:

1. `Drain` the `node` will all the containers, The containers will stop and will be started on other nodes depending on your `scheduling strategy`. the downside to this is you will have one empty `node`. (the drained node)
2. You can stop/remove services, and recreate them, Using `Bundles` will help you to stay consistent and do it faster, It will cause the containers to distribute on your `nodes` depending on your `scheduling strategy`.